# display:inline block but move divs as high as possible

Tags: html, css

I have two divs that I would like to be side-by side if the screen is wide enough but if it's a narrow screen I want them to display one below the other, basically like inline block will do. the problem with inline block is the shorter one is as low as it can go on the 'line', like a full stop next to a bigger letter. how can I make the two divs go as high as possible on the 'line' so the white space is below the smaller div not above it, more like a quote mark next to a letter

either div could be taller than the other

Comment: You might try using "float: left ;" rather than display: inline.

Comment: Sorry you did not like the suggestion of float: left.   That tends to have the same affect as inline by allowing multiple divs to float in a row, yet, still wrap down if there is not enough room.   Also, float would tend to pack to the top of the space available unless the area is defined to a line to center or bottom ... and it is very reliable.

Comment: I would be interested to know why the float has been down voted? This should give the exact result requested in the question.

Comment: I didn't downvote the answer, but I would imagine it is because it does not solve the problem. The solution to this problem would require a `vertical-align` (as answered by @JezenThomas) - which would not work if `float: left` was used - and possibly CSS `media-queries`. I don't think the question is clear enough to determine a full solution.

Comment: I don't see any reason why you wouldn't use float here either. As user1760422 states - the two divs will align top by default and the second div will go under the first if there is not enough space to go side-by-side. Wrap both in a .clearfix and you're sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

However, without seeing your test case it's difficult to discern whether or not there are other metrics involved that are creating that space, *e.g.*, margin, padding etc.